Undefined array key "default_language"
i am having this issue on my laravel app, am trying to implement change language middleware but i keep getting this error undefined array key.
This is the middleware snippet
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $localeLanguage = \Session::get('languageChangeName');
        $defaultLanguage = getSuperAdminSettingValue()['default_language']->value;
        if (! isset($localeLanguage)) {
            if(!empty($defaultLanguage)){
                \App::setLocale($defaultLanguage);
                $defaultLanguage;
            }else{
                \App::setLocale('en');
            }
        } else {
            \App::setLocale($localeLanguage);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}


That error has occurred because the supposed array being returned by the getSuperAdminSettingValue method does not contain "default_language" key as part of the data in the array. I would suggest you assign the response from the method to a variable on a seperate line and then dd it to check what is returned before continuing with the rest of the implementation.
$superAdminSettingValues = getSuperAdminSettingValue();
/* 
 * The line below is to be deleted before proceeding to the next line
 * after confirming the variable is not an empty array and has the 
 * default_language as part of its data
 */
dd($superAdminSettingValues); 
$defaultLanguage = $superAdminSettingValues['default_language']->value;

I would encourage you to read on Laravel Localization. It is used to handle situations such as this in your laravel project. It involves using the command

php artisan lang:publish

to publish the language files from laravel in your project and setting a default language for your app in the config/app.php file. After which, I would approach the code a little differently using the following steps

Publish the lang file with the command above

Set the default locale in the config/app.php file by assigning a value to the APP_LOCALE key.
As such, we would always have a value for default locale except if the value is not set in the config file. Then my code will be like this
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
 {
     /*
      * Get the locale language set in the session provided it has been 
      * set earlier somewhere else.
      */
      $localeLanguage = \Session::get('languageChangeName');

     /* 
      * Get the current locale value i.e app default locale
      */
     $currentLocale = \App::currentLocale();

     if (isset($localeLanguage)) {
         \App::setLocale($localeLanguage);
     } else {
         if (!isset($currentLocale)) {
             \App::setLocale('en');
         }
     }

     return $next($request);
 }




default_language is not found in the array, is there away i can implement the the function without the default_language

As I can only use comments to ask for clarity, I have updated my original post with more information on this. I hope this is able to help, best wishes.
